# java.lang.Throwable: addInArray in ListView with SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, simpleadapter

I have an Activity with ListView with SimpleAdapter.

Activity:

```
public class TankListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnShowResult {

    private final String ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER = "Number";
    private final String ATTRIBUTE_FUEL = "Fuel";
    private final String ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY = "Capacity";
    private final String ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY_CURRENT = "Capacity Current";


    private SimpleAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> tankList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tank_list);

        tankList = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER, ATTRIBUTE_FUEL, ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY_CURRENT, ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY};
        int[] to = {R.id.textview_tankitem_number, R.id.textview_tankitem_fuel, R.id.textview_tankitem_capacity_current, R.id.textview_tankitem_capacity};
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), tankList, R.layout.tank_list_item, from, to);
        adapter.setViewBinder(new TankItemBinder());

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_tanklistactivity_list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
        registerForContextMenu(list);
    }

    // ...

    class TankItemBinder implements SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object o, String s) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.textview_tankitem_number:
                int i = (int)o;
                ((TextView)view).setText("№" + ((i < 0)?"":i));
                return true;

            case R.id.textview_tankitem_fuel:
                ((TextView)view).setText((String)o);
                return true;

            case R.id.textview_tankitem_capacity:
                ((TextView)view).setText(o + " л");
                return true;

            case R.id.textview_tankitem_capacity_current:
                ((TextView)view).setText(o + " л");
                return true;

            default: return false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

I'm adding items to the list after parsing incoming data:

```
@Override
public void showResult(Request request) {

    // ...
    // parsing total count
    // ...

    Map<String, Object> item;
    while(tankList.size() < total) {
        item = new HashMap<>();
        item.put(ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER, -1);
        item.put(ATTRIBUTE_FUEL, "Loading...");
        item.put(ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY_CURRENT, 0);
        item.put(ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY, 0);
        tankList.add(item);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // ...
    // parsing data
    // ...

    // adding items:
    for(int i = 0; i < size / 19; i++) {
        try {
            tankIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize + i;
            if(tankIndex > tankList.size()) { break; }

            HashMap<String, Object> m = (HashMap<String, Object>) tankList.get(tankIndex);
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER, Integer.parseInt(r.get(i*19 + 1), 16));
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_FUEL, r.get(i*19 + 2));
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY_CURRENT, Integer.parseInt(r.get(i*19 + 3), 16));
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY, Integer.parseInt(r.get(i*19 + 4), 16));
            tankList.set(tankIndex, m);
        } catch (Exception err) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing: " + err.getMessage());
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The problem is `java.lang.Throwable: addInArray` debug message appear each time when I'm calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and it is slowing down rendering:

```
D/ViewGroup﹕ addInArray been called, this = android.widget.ListView{4224c658 VFED.VCL .F....ID 0,96-540,922 #7f0700af app:id/listview_tanklistactivity_list}call stack =
    java.lang.Throwable: addInArray
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3786)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3740)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout(ViewGroup.java:3687)
            at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1862)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1815)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1631)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2149)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2023)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

What I have noticed so far: if `tankList` is initialized by some value before creating SimpleAdapter, this message won't appear:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tank_list);

    tankList = new ArrayList<>();

    // this solve the problem:
    Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
    item.put(ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER, -1);
    item.put(ATTRIBUTE_FUEL, "Loading...");
    item.put(ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY_CURRENT, 0);
    item.put(ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY, 0);
    tankList.add(item);


    String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER, ATTRIBUTE_FUEL, ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY_CURRENT, ATTRIBUTE_CAPACITY};
    int[] to = {R.id.textview_tankitem_number, R.id.textview_tankitem_fuel, R.id.textview_tankitem_capacity_current, R.id.textview_tankitem_capacity};
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), tankList, R.layout.tank_list_item, from, to);
    adapter.setViewBinder(new TankItemBinder());

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_tanklistactivity_list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    registerForContextMenu(list);
}
```

But I need this list to be empty on load. How to fix that?

Comment: please share code for `TankItemBinder`

Comment: @0X0nosugar, added. It's inner class of activity

Comment: @0X0nosugar , on different devices I have 5-7 items on the screen. But I don't understand what it can matter. Please, pay attention to my note which I had made in the post: If the list is initialized at least by one value, there are no messages, regardless of the size of a screen, contents of the list and also elements of which it consists (in my application there are more than ten different lists builded by this principle and all of them give this error message).